# Random numbers using system time all the same

Tags: c++, random

I have written a function in C++ that used the system time from `time.h` as a seed and returns a pseudo-random number between two specified values.

```
#include <time.h>

int randInt(int min, int max)
{
    int nSeed = time(NULL);
    int nRandom = nSeed * 13;
    nRandom = nRandom % (max + 1);
    nRandom += min;
    return nRandom;
}
```

The function does exactly what it is supposed to do (as far as I can tell). However, when I repeatedly call the function, for example, when using a `for` loop to fill an array with pseudo-random numbers, almost no time has passed and therefore the seed is the same, making each number in the array the same. How could I solve this problem? Is there a way of getting a time from the system that is to a smaller precision? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: Quick fix would be declaring the `nSeed` `static` and using it instad of `nRandom`

Comment: You should not be generating a random number yourself. It's a very hard thing to do properly. You should look into system libraries that generate random numbers such as `arc4random()`.

Comment: Why are you implementing your own PRNG? Especially since this is an extremely weak LCG rather than a *good* PRNG like MT. Even `rand` on most systems - rather weak by today's standards - is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out you should not reseed for each call to your function.

However the concrete problem you have with getting the same number for two calls to `randInt` is more likely due to the fact that `time` returns time in *seconds*. Thus for one second all calls to your function will use the exact same seed and thus return the exact same value.

But I strongly recommend to use either [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) which is part of C++11 or [boost::random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) which is essentially the same for older versions of C++

Answer (score 3):

You should get a seed (e.g. the time) *once*, and then generate several values by repeatedly applying a step function. Without, your "PRNG" is just a hash function applies to the seed generation, which is usually not very random. Separating the seed from the step function also allows deterministic operation (fixed seed) for debugging or reproducible results.

Answer (score 1):

You must not repeatedly seed a PRNG while you generate a sequence of random values. Seed once only, typically at the start of your program.

The problem that you have encountered is an obvious consequence of erroneous re-seeding. A much more serious problem is that re-seeding will likely destroy the distributional properties of your PRNG.

One big problem with your PRNG, is that you do not store the previous generated value. Which is what has led you to re-seed each time you sample. The solution is to remember the previous value that the PRNG generated, and start from that rather than `time(NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply add some delay or sleep in order not to have the same time in the seed, but as others suggested you should not generate your own PRNG, you may want to add some mouse position, some packets receive, or other factors in order to increase the randomness but it will still not a good way to generate random numbers.

Comment: Sleep is shockingly bad advice here. What it you need a million samples?

Comment: Beyond that, consider the distributional properties.